# How can I let a task run all the time on a linux v-server?

Tags: python, linux

I would like to develop a web game. It is based on a database (MySQL) and is intended to run on a Linux server. My question is: Can I write a Python program that I store on the server and that runs nonstop and performs actions on the data in the database? And then run a website on the same server that can then access the data in the database and also carry out actions on it? Later I would also like to create this website as an Android or iOS app.

So far I've mainly read up on Django to develop the web game. But it doesn't seem to be 100% suitable for developing the web game with. So which tool would be best suited to develop the game with?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I write a Python program that I store on the server and that runs nonstop and performs actions on the data in the database?

Yes. You'd set it up to run via e.g. a [systemd unit](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files).

> And then run a website on the same server that can then access the data in the database and also carry out actions on it?

Yes. The details vary (you could use Django, no problem there), but that'd also be set up to run via e.g. a systemd unit, within an application server like uWSGI or Gunicorn, and likely fronted by a web server like Caddy or Nginx.